# How to configure a list of sub-components from outside the host?

Tags: angular

I want to create an Angular component that renders a group of buttons.

```
<div class="button-group">
  <button (onclick)="handleClick1">First text</button>
  <button (onclick)="handleClick2">Another text</button>
...more buttons here...
</div>
```

I want to be able to configure the buttons(text, cklickhandles etc.) from outside of the host.
Most preferably would be to add buttons using directives.

```
<buttongroup playButton stopButton />
```

Where playButton and stopButton is directives with predefined buttons.

Is this possible? Is it a good design? I there a more Angular-type-of-way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could possibly do that, the question is, *is it worth the effort? If you don't have any particular reason for doing it.*

We could use the concept of [Feature toggling](https://netbasal.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-implementing-feature-flags-in-angular-applications-d4ae1fd33684) to basically toggle the buttons except the part that we would be passing the value of the json (in our case an array of string) and the directive would match it with the array of string.

And to handle the click event, we would need the component to throw out `@Output` `EventEmitter`

And it would be something it like such

app.component.ts

```
<buttongroup [buttons]="['play','stop']" (click)="onButtonClicked($event)"/>
```

button-group.component.html

```
<div class="button-group">
    <button *visibleButtons="['play']" (click)="handleClick(1)">Play</button>
    <button *visibleButtons="['stop']" (click)="handleClick(2)">Stop</button>
    ...more buttons here...
</div>
```

---

On the flip side, if your use-case is simply *need to configure buttons from outside of the host*, perhaps look into `Content Projection`

app.component.html

```
<buttonGroup>
    <button (click)="handlePlay()">Play</button>
    <button (click)="handleStop()">Stop</button>
</buttonGroup>
```

and in `button-group.component.html` simply place `<ng-content>` tag where you want to project the buttons

Comment: Thank you! Maybe contentchildren and directives is better way to do this. Have a look at my [new question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63736932/derive-och-subclass-a-directive-so-contentchildren-can-find-it)